# D3 line chart plotting backwards despite y axis being incremental in nature

Tags: d3.js

I have a mix of a line chart and bar chart in D3. Though the y-axis(dates) mapped to 'usageDate' is incremental in nature, the resulting line graph seems to plot in the reverse direction.

Image
[LineChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMqst.png)

The Line chart plots *'usageTrendDetails'* on the X and *usageDate* on Y. Attaching a link with the code.
[Clickhere](http://jsbin.com/layawu)

The line chart is plotting from left to right, however as highlighted in the image, it suddenly begins plotting from right to left and then goes back in the right direction. Any idea why this happening?

Comment: Is it possible that your data has not been sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is sorted, the issue was with the way dates were being formatted after September. The logic for pre-pending a zero for months 0(Jan) to 8(Sep) wasn't handling Oct, Nov and Dec correctly, resulting in the months after September plotting backwards.

OLD CODE :
 `if(month<= 8){
            month = "0"+(month+1);
        }`

NEW CODE : Handling Oct - Dec

```
if(month<= 8){
        month = "0"+(month+1);
    }else{
        month = month + 1;
    }
```

Here's the graph after the issue is fixed.

[Click Here](http://jsbin.com/suyivu/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0):

Sort your data before making the line:

```
data = data.sort(function(a,b){return a.date.getTime() - b.date.getTime();})
```

working code [here](http://jsbin.com/vicewekepe/1/edit?html,output)